# "Upload Multiple Files" link is not available for blog post. How to enable it?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload

I have blog where people can share their stories with pictures and documents. Sometimes they have to put 10 documents in a single blog posts. Right now, my upload file pop-up window for the blog post doesn't have a "Upload Multiple Files... " link. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

That option is only available with IE and you need to enable the ActiveX setting and that should work.

Unfortunately, IE is the only supported browser by MS.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are they using? I seem to recall upload multiple files is only an IE thing.

Comment: I am using IE only. It doesn't work for other browsers...