# How to enable multiple upload for document library in other browsers other than IE?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, document-library, file-upload, browser-compatibility

I am using SharePoint 2010. I know that IE is the supported browser for uploading multiple documents. Wanted to know if there is any way to use the upload multiple documents in other browser like chrome, Firefox or edge? Whether be it extensions or other means?  Thank you. [This is a link to show how to enable multiple downloads for IE only](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64553/upload-multiple-files-link-is-not-available-for-blog-post-how-to-enable-it)

Answer (score 1):

The other way to open document library in explorer is by running command `file://sharepointaddress/sites/docsites/doclibraryname` in windows run. This didn't work if you put it in SharePoint 2013 link, I had tried it.
After you open that explorer windows, you could just copy and paste multiple files to it.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting approach that works very well, but does not address all the other browsers.